# Git - file flags conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using bitbucket and end up with a conflict, code is perfectly same, but when I try to merge

I'm getting "file flags conflict", I've tried to google but didn't find much information about that particular issue, maybe anyone can give me a clue what I need to look for?

I've compare permissions and it's the same on both files.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I did next:

1. Pushed my local changes to the remote repository. Everything went okay.
2. Created pull-request to the main repository.
3. When owner tried to accept pull-request "file flags conflict" appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be a BitBucket server issue, when merging from a fork (like accepting a Pull Request).
See for instance this [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/kfsone/tradedangerous/issue/30/file-flags-changes-on-tradepy).

[image: https://bitbucket-assetroot.s3.amazonaws.com/repository/9A9dGk/1502768015-Screenshot%20-%2017_10_2014%20%2C%2016_13_00.png?Signature=benFOwMQs7KcYfNtZJ6yM%2BlqKbo%3D&Expires=1415619877&AWSAccessKeyId=0EMWEFSGA12Z1HF1TZ82]

> I always merge local. Have you tried?
>
> - add the remote: `git remote add kfsone https://bitbucket.org/kfsone/tradedangerous.git`
> - and than you can just: `git pull kfsone master`
>
> Merging locally does the trick.

So if this is a conflict shown by BitBucket on the server side, try cloning and merging locally first, then push back to the remote repo.

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds! :)

Comment: Updated my question with the actions I did just in case.